# Current flow in Ethernet driver

Tags: voltage, pcb, transformer, impedance, ethernet

Below is an example of an Ethernet PHY - current mode PHY driver.

The voltage given to the Vcc of the PHY is 3.3 V. Image for reference on page 3 of this [doc](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/LAN8720A%20QFN%20Rev%20D%20Schematic%20Checklist.pdf)

I want to understand how does the current flow on the TXP/RXP pins of the PHY in the current mode driver? Since, in a current mode driver, external pull-up termination resistors are there.

My questions:

1. [image]

Can someone tell me the current flow path in the above image when Ethernet signals are present on the TX lines? How will the current flow be through the transformer and the PHY?
And like what would be the voltage on the ethernet lines?

2. Since there are 50 Ω termination resistors, the impedance of the ethernet traces TX/RX should able be 50 Ω on the PCB for impedance matching, correct?

Comment: The current can really only flow one way- from txp/txn to gnd. The phy pulls either txp or txd low depending on if it wants to send a 1 or 0 bit. This description is a simplification.  The manufacturer gives guidance on the required pcb layout.

Comment: Freshman, if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TX pins are, by themselves like an open-collector output. Therefore they need a pull-up resistor to make them work. That's the first point.

Also, because the collector (or drain) of a BJT (or MOSFET) acts like a current source/sink (i.e. very high impedance), you might as well make the pull-up resistors associated with those pins 50 Ω so that they are compatible with the impedance seen at the magnetics interface.

That makes them equivalent to a voltage source in series with 50 Ω.